# Why the order of hashmap items get changed?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

I am using the following code in my interface, once the results are shown on the browser the order of the values get changed. how to solve the problem?

```
   public static final Map<String,String> BED = new HashMap<String,String>(){
        {
            put("A","Any");
            put("0","Studio");
            put("1","1 or more");
            put("2","2 or more");
            put("4","4 or more");


    };
    };


<s:select name="BED" label="Bedrooms" list="@interfaces.Items@BED"/>
```

in browser the order is as following

```
 1 or more
 Studio
 Any 
 4 or more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashmap is not a ordered collection.

So if you change to TreeMap or LinkedHashMap based on the use case then you will get the result in ordered way.

From [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html):

> The Java platform contains three general-purpose Map implementations: HashMap, TreeMap, and LinkedHashMap. Their behavior and performance are precisely analogous to HashSet, TreeSet, and LinkedHashSet, as described in The [Set Interface section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html).

Set Interface Section:

> The Java platform contains three general-purpose Set implementations: HashSet, TreeSet, and LinkedHashSet. HashSet, which stores its elements in a hash table, is the best-performing implementation; however it makes no guarantees concerning the order of iteration. TreeSet, which stores its elements in a red-black tree, orders its elements based on their values; it is substantially slower than HashSet. LinkedHashSet, which is implemented as a hash table with a linked list running through it, orders its elements based on the order in which they were inserted into the set (insertion-order). LinkedHashSet spares its clients from the unspecified, generally chaotic ordering provided by HashSet at a cost that is only slightly higher.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `LinkedHashMap` instead

```
public static final Map<String,String> BED = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
```

**Reference**:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

> This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the *iteration ordering*, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (*insertion-order*).